# React useContext doesn't update the state value between pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-context

I'm learning how to use useContext, and I made a shopping cart (Next JS - app router) exercise where I manage the value of the cart globally.

But when I add items to the cart state on the "products" page and try to pass this value to the "cart" page, the state is only reading the initial value of the cart, which is an empty array, not the updated value.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The initial value of the cart was empty, so I added an object to ensure that the value of the cart was passing to the cart page

```
//cartContext.jsx

'use client'
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const CartContext = createContext();

export default function CartProvider({ children }) {

    const [cart, setCart] = useState([{
      id:65615656,
      title:'prueba',
      price:'000',
  },]);

    const addToCart = (item) => {
      const newCart = [...cart, item];
      setCart(newCart);
      console.log("funciona");
      console.log(cart);
    }

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{cart, addToCart}}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

```
//products page

'use client'
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SomeProvider, { CartContext } from '../context/cartContext';
import ListItem from '../components/ListItem';
import CartProvider from '../context/cartContext';

const url = 'https://fakestoreapi.com/products';

export default function Page() {

    const { cart, addToCart } = useContext(CartContext);
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        async function fetchData(){
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const data = await response.json();
                setProducts(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [])

    useEffect(()=>{
        
    }, [])

    return (
        <CartProvider>
          <div>
            <ul>
              {products.map(item=>(
                <ListItem 
                key={item.id}
                title={item.title}
                price={item.price}
                onHandleClick={()=>addToCart(item)}></ListItem>
              ))}
            </ul>  
          </div>
          </CartProvider>
    );
}
```

```
//cart page

'use client'
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { CartContext } from '../context/cartContext'
import LiCart from '../components/LiCart';
import CartProvider from '../context/cartContext';

export default function Page() {

  const {cart} = useContext(CartContext);

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(cart);
  }, [cart])

  return (
    
    <CartProvider>
      <div>
      <ul>
      {cart.map(item => (
        <LiCart 
        key={item.id}
        title={item.title}
        price={item.price}>
        </LiCart>
      ))}
      </ul>
      
    </div>
    </CartProvider>
  )
}
```

```
//layout.js

import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import CartProvider from './context/cartContext'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <CartProvider>{children}</CartProvider>
        </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Initially, I thought that maybe I was mutating the array instead of updating it, so I changed the addToCart function, but it still doesn't work either.

Comment: _"initial value of the cart, which is an empty array"_... no it's not 

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The initial value of the cart was empty, so I added an object to ensure that the value of the cart was passing to the cart page. I forgot to delete it...

Comment: It looks like you're using multiple nested providers, which would explain the behavior. You only need one, which should contain all the components using it. The code you've posted is not sufficient  to run the app and therefore cannot be debugged. I suggest creating a *runnable* [mcve] (on codesandbox.io or similar) making sure it reproduces the bug. If you need further help, that is.

Comment: Yeah, remove `<CartProvider>` from the products page (well spotted @tao)

Comment: @taoI tried to remove the providers, but nothing happens. [Here is a CodeSandbox link with the code](https://shorturl.at/dftL3)

Comment: The link you provided doesn't seem to work, it redirects to https://www.shorturl.at/. Provide the actual link, not a shortened one. Also note you need to add a space or punctuation after someone's mention in order for them to be notified (e.g: I wasn't notified by your comment, because `@tao` was followed by `I`).

Answer (score -1):

It might be beacuse the CartContext isn't passed in correctly.
try exporting as such:

```js
// CartContext.js

const CartContext = createContext();

const CartProvider = function({ children }) {

    const [cart, setCart] = useState([{
      id:65615656,
      title:'prueba',
      price:'000',
  },]);

    const addToCart = (item) => {
      const newCart = [...cart, item];
      setCart(newCart);
      console.log("funciona");
      console.log(cart);
    }

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{cart, addToCart}}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  )
}
export {CartContext, CartProvider}
```

P.S Remove the empty `useEffect()` from `product page`, it could cause rerenders

Comment: There's nothing wrong with OP's exports. Also, `useEffect()` does not cause renders. In fact, it's the opposite; renders cause `useEffect()` to run